# Yii2 how to make submit button from html a

Tags: forms, yii2, send

```
  <?= '<li>'
           . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'], 'post')
                  . Html::submitButton(
                            'Exit(admin)',
                            ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']
                                      )
           . Html::endForm()
    . '</li>'?>
```

This code is working, but I want to change submit button to `html::a`. When I try to  do it, it's not working.

Comment: Because the link you generate does not submit the form. To do so, you'll have to point the link to `#` and submit the form with js/jQuery

Comment: Logout action don't require any form. Seems useless to me. Use simple anchor for logout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommend to use a link as submit button, anyhow if you want, here is code

```
<?php echo Html::a('Exit(admin)',$url=false,['class'=>'btn btn-warning','onclick'=>'submitForm()']); ?>
```

in javascript

```
function submitForm(){
 document.getElementById('FormId').submit;
}
```